# Using suptitle overrides ('visible', 'off') figure property in matlab

Tags: plot, matlab, matlab-figure

I am producing a large number of graphs in matlab R2011b. I would like to make use of the ('visible', 'off') figure property so that I don't need to display each plot on the screen---each plot contains a *lot* of data and several subplots so rendering them takes up time and unnecessary processing power (I save them directly to an image).

Each plot contains four subplots and I would like to add a super "title" to each figure. I have been using `suptitle` (part of the bioinfo toolbox) but it appears that using suptitle undoes the effect of ('visible, 'off') and the figure is displayed anyway.

```
xdata = -100:1:100;
ydata = -100:1:100;
zdata = rand(1,201)*-50;

fig1 = figure(1)
set(fig1, 'visible', 'off')
subplot(2,1,1)
scatter(xdata, ydata, 10, zdata)
title('Small title 1')
subplot(2,1,2)
scatter(xdata, ydata, 10, zdata)
title('small title 2')
suptitle('This is a big title')
```

Using this code, the graph is displayed. If the `suptitle` line is commented out then the figure is not displayed (which is what I want).

Does anyone know

1. Why this happens?
2. How I can fix it /work around it? Is there another way of adding a large title to a figure with subplots?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have this toolbox. Can you put the source of this `suptitle.m`?

Comment: Some possible alternatives: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-15OZ8/?solution=1-15OZ8
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/171543
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454369/matlab-subplot-title-and-axes-labels

Comment: @Andrey this isn't the exact version, but its very similar: http://willame.francois.free.fr/edu/xjobb/doc/SIMULHOPE/simulhope/plot/suptitle.html .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just copy this line to the end of your sample code:

```
 set(fig1, 'visible', 'off')
```

This should solve your issue...

Comment: I already tried this and it is only a partial fix. The graph is rendered on the screen and *then* disappears.

Comment: Interesting. I only see this when I move the line to the end of the code. If 2 copies of that line appear at the beginning and the end of the code, no figure is generated ...

Comment: Ahh, I hadn't tried putting that line in twice---just moving it to the end. If you put it in twice it seems to work. A hack, but it works. Thanks :)

Comment: Unfortunatley, this workoaround does not work in my MATLAB 2017a. The bug still exists.